# Import File with several XMLs in it to excel as a table

Tags: xml, excel

I am trying to import a file into an excel sheet that contains several xml files inside. Like the following:

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one identification line (

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string rootTag = "Root";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);
            string xml = "";
            string inputLine = "";
            int lineCount = 0;
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if(++lineCount > 2)
                {
                    if(inputLine.StartsWith("<?xml") || inputLine.StartsWith("<" + rootTag) || inputLine.StartsWith("</" + rootTag))
                    {
                        inputLine = "";  //remove line
                    }
                }
                xml += inputLine;

            }

            //add back closing tag
            xml += "</" + rootTag + ">";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider extracting the individual xml files from that one large raw file. Afterwards, read into Excel those individual files.

Here is a VBA macro for the extraction solution:

```
Sub ExtractXML()
    Dim strPath As String, DataLine As String, strOutput As String, strNewPath As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim fso As Object, oFile As Object
    Dim i As Long

    strPath = "C\Path\To\XMLRawFile.xml"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open strPath For Input As #FileNum

    strOutput = ""

    i = 1
    While Not EOF(FileNum)

        ' READ EACH LINE OF RAW XML FILE
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        strOutput = strOutput & DataLine & vbNewLine

        ' OUTPUT INDIVIUDAL FILES AT THE END OF EACH ROOT NODE       
        If DataLine = "</Root>" Then                
            strNewPath = "C\Path\To\XMLNewFile" & i & ".xml"
            Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strNewPath)

            oFile.WriteLine strOutput
            oFile.Close

            strOutput = ""
            Set oFile = Nothing

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend

    Set fso = Nothing
    MsgBox "Successfully extracted raw xml into multiple xml files!", vbInformation

End Sub
```